# Xampp cant run MySQL in localhost! - " Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly."

Tags: mysql

Today i tried to run MySQL in localhost ,but shutdown immediately.

Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
    This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
    improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
    Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
    the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
    If you need more help, copy and post this
    entire log window on the forums

I really cant find the issue.

Comment: Open MySQL  data folder and delete files starting with `ib`

Answer (score 0):

This error is occurring because the default port that MySQL uses(3306) has been already taken by another task. in that case you can kill the running PID and start it again.

**Solution 1:**

```
taskkill /pid <port>
```

Steps:

1. Go to netstat and find the PID for MySQL.
2. Kill the PID in the command prompt using the command that is mentioned above.
3. Then start mysql again.

[image]

[image: The highlighted one is the PID]

**Solution 2:**

1. exit Xampp server
2. go to your C:\xampp\mysql\data directory
3. delete the ibdata1 file
4. restart xampp server

   I hope this will solve your issue.